# Hadoop ranking columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

So I have these specific columns that I'm working with: 
`customer_token`, `merchant_id`, `merchant_category_code`, and `transaction_amount`.

My current query is this:

```
SELECT customer_token, COUNT(transaction_amount), SUM(transaction_amount)
FROM transaction 
                     WHERE file_date>20121031 
                     and file_date<20121201
GROUP BY customer_token
```

I want add on to the above query a part where in the result, the merchant_category_code is separated into different columns based on the transaction amount in each specific `merchant_category_code`. A result that would look something like this:

> customer_token, count(transaction_amount),sum(transaction_amount), count(transaction_amount in merchant_category_code which is ranked 1), count(transaction_amount in merchant_category_code which is ranked 2), count(transaction_amount in merchant_category_code which is ranked 3), etc...

and then this:

> customer_token, count(transaction_amount),sum(transaction_amount), sum(transaction_amount in merchant_category_code which is ranked 1), sum(transaction_amount in merchant_category_code which is ranked 2), sum(transaction_amount in merchant_category_code which is ranked 3), etc...

But I'm at a loss on how to do this or if it is even at all possible.

Comment: I'm only using hive. I tagged sql by accident. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know in advance what the possible values of `merchant_category_code` are, you can use `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT customer_token,
       COUNT(transaction_amount),
       SUM(transaction_amount),
       COUNT(CASE WHEN merchant_category_code = 1 THEN transaction_amount END),
       COUNT(CASE WHEN merchant_category_code = 2 THEN transaction_amount END),
       COUNT(CASE WHEN merchant_category_code = 3 THEN transaction_amount END),
       ...
       SUM(CASE WHEN merchant_category_code = 1 THEN transaction_amount END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN merchant_category_code = 2 THEN transaction_amount END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN merchant_category_code = 3 THEN transaction_amount END),
       ...
  FROM transaction 
 WHERE file_date BETWEEN 20121101 AND 20121130
 GROUP
    BY customer_token
;
```

(or `IF` expressions, if you prefer; for documentation on both of these, see [the section titled "Conditional Functions" on the page "LanguageManual+UDF" in the Hive wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions)).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a bunch, that was a ton of help.